# How to install nodejs on Docker?(Windows Container)

Tags: node.js, docker

I've just created docker image of my spring boot application and I've implemented some functions that require nodejs. I searched and tried various ways but could not figure it  out how to make node command could be run on Docker.

I've pulled node into Docker.

```
docker pull node
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre 
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/testdemo-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war /testdemo-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/testdemo-1.1.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war"]
```

Because of some memory issue, I've had a problem switching to Linux Container , so please tell me how to install nodejs on Windows container. I've just started Docker so please go easy on me.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT
I added this line to my Dockerfile

```
RUN msiexec.exe /a https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3-x64.msi /quiet
```

Whild building a docker image I get this error.

```
Step 2/6 : RUN msiexec.exe /a https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3-x64.msi /quiet
 ---> Running in 3b025a7238f2
T h i s   i n s t a l l a t i o n   p a c k a g e   c o u l d   n o t   b e   o p e n e d .     
V e r i f y   t h a t   t h e   p a c k a g e   e x i s t s   a n d   t h a t   y o u   c a n   a c c e s s   i t ,  
 o r   c o n t a c t   t h e   a p p l i c a t i o n   v e n d o r   t o   v e
```

Building a docker image is successfully done after all but I still get "'node' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, ..." error if my spring boot application trying to use node command.

Comment: You shouldn't need to actually _install_ Node, it's a standalone binary

Answer (score 3):

While Marek's answer will probably work; please make sure you use the latest version of node, since node 8 is officially EOL.

You can also add the installation command to your Dockerfile, this way your application actually works upon starting the docker container:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre 
RUN msiexec.exe /a https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3-x64.msi /quiet
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/testdemo-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war /testdemo-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/testdemo-1.1.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war"]
```

Comment: I added your suggested command in my dockerfile but still get node is not an available command. I also edited my question could you please check that verification error? Should I set up a new Docker settings?

Comment: Can you try changing /a to /i?
So RUN msiexec.exe **/i** https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3-x64.msi /quiet

Comment: I changed it to /i and rebuild docker image but still got that error. I also tried changing docker settings(Docker Engine)   "experimental": to true, this time every steps run fine without errors but after I run docker image and tried to command node --version I still get "node command cannot be found".

Comment: Changing `/a` to `/i` works. Tested on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8` Docker image and Azure DevOps

Answer (score 1):

You haven't *pulled node into Docker*. By doing `docker pull node` you actually download official node image from dockerhub (https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).

What you actually have to do is actually pull node within your docker container. Simplest approach how to do it from command line once you are in your windows container:

```
msiexec.exe /a https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.3.0/node-v8.3.0-x64.msi /quiet
```

Let me know if it worked.